# npm run watch stops working - Laravel with Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I am running a Laravel project with Vue.js frontend.
Running `npm run watch` always worked for me and whenever I did changes, they directly appear.
Suddenly my changes are not showing anymore and I don't know what the problem is.

I tried `node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --watch-poll --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` and it didnt work either.

P.S: im not getting errors

Comment: Have you cleared cache in your browser?

Comment: It worked by running ```npm run watch-poll```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by running `npm run watch-poll`